# How do i make the selected areas transparent, so i wouldn't have to place this logo only on a white background?

Tags: svg, transparency

The whole logo is drawn in adobe illustrator CS6 with pen only. I'm new to illustrator, so any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Which "selected areas"? Have you forgotten to post a screenshot?

Comment: This needs guessing. Show a simplified example and tell what is the problematic "selected area". Illustrator generally saves and exports images without the background except JPGs and the simplest PNGs. Without an example you will get voted out. An example probably calls soon a pinpoint answer. If one already added answer happens to be the right one, accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving a file as an SVG, it should automatically have a transparent background. However, if I understand you correctly, there is part of the logo that is displayed as "white" when it really should be cut out from the pattern. For example, in this sample graphic, the white part should be "cut out" and not a separate item. The easiest way to extract it is to use the Pathfinder tool and, selecting both objects, choose to Exclude the top part (in this case, the white smaller star). Then that part is excluded from the larger graphic.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make an image file that contains only your object, so the background is transparent you must export a vector file type.

To do that go to File>Save for Web. The new version may say File>Export>Save for Web.

Your best option is to save it as a .PNG 24 - transparency.

If you want a certain size rectangle around your logo than make your artboard that size. If you don't care and only want your logo big and to the edge then don't check "use artboard bounding box".

The .PNG you export will be only your logo, not the background.

Comment: PNG is not a "vector file type." It is a raster file type, so the first sentence of the answer is contradicted by the recommendation to use PNG.

Comment: Yes .PNG is not vector but for this application I think it's "close enough". There's no other display ready file type that has clear background except .SVG. I recommend using .PNG format when using logos as bitmaps.